Какие могут быть причины блокировки аккаунта , скрипт по рассылке телеграм

import random
import asyncio

from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.functions.contacts import ImportContactsRequest
from telethon.tl.types import InputPhoneContact

# Функция для загрузки данных из файлов с указанием кодировки
def load_data(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        return file.read().strip()

# Загрузка данных из файлов
api_id, api_hash = load_data('api.txt').split(':')
phones = load_data('phones.txt').split('\n')

# Функция для авторизации
async def auth(api_id, api_hash):
    client = TelegramClient('session', api_id, api_hash)
    await client.start()
    return client

# Функция для добавления контакта
async def add_contact(client, phone):
    try:
        # Добавляем контакт в список контактов
        await client(ImportContactsRequest(contacts=[InputPhoneContact(client_id=0, phone=phone, first_name=phone, last_name='')]))

        print(f"Контакт {phone} добавлен.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Ошибка при добавлении контакта {phone}: {e}")

# Функция для отправки сообщения без добавления в контакты
async def send_message_without_contact(client, phone, message):
    try:
        # Отправляем сообщение без добавления в контакты
        await client.send_message(phone, message)
        print(f"Сообщение отправлено на номер: {phone}")
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Ошибка при отправке на номер {phone}: {e}")
        return False

# Функция для отправки сообщений
async def send_messages(client):
    # Загрузка сообщений из файла
    with open('message.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        message_modules = file.read().strip().split('+++')

    # Запрос количества сообщений для отправки
    num_messages = int(input("Введите количество сообщений для отправки: "))

    # Запрос диапазона задержки между сообщениями
    delay_range_start, delay_range_end = map(int, input("Введите диапазон задержки между сообщениями (в секундах), через пробел: ").split())

    # Переменные для статистики
    sent_count = 0
    not_sent = []

    # Отправка сообщений
    for phone in phones:
        # Выбираем случайный модуль из списка модулей
        random_module = random.choice(message_modules)
        await add_contact(client, phone)  # Добавляем контакт перед отправкой сообщения
        if await send_message_without_contact(client, phone, random_module):
            sent_count += 1
            if sent_count >= num_messages:
                break
        else:
            not_sent.append(phone)
        # Выбираем случайное время задержки из диапазона и ждем
        delay = random.randint(delay_range_start, delay_range_end)
        print(f"Следующее сообщение будет отправлено через {delay} секунд")
        await asyncio.sleep(delay)

    # Вывод статистики
    print(f"Отправлено сообщений: {sent_count}/{num_messages}")
    print("Номера, на которые не были отправлены сообщения:")
    for phone in not_sent:
        print(phone)

    # Ожидание нажатия Enter для завершения программы
    input("Для выхода нажмите Enter...")

# Главная функция
async def main():
    # Авторизация
    client = await auth(api_id, api_hash)

    while True:
        # Запрос действия пользователя
        action = int(input("Выберите действие:\n1. Отправить сообщения\n2. Выйти из программы\nВведите номер действия: "))

        if action == 1:
            # Оставляем текущую логику для отправки сообщений
            await send_messages(client)
        elif action == 2:
            break
        else:
            print("Некорректный выбор действия.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())


Причины могут быть разные. К чему тут этот скрипт?

Скрипт заключается в рассылке выгодных условий должникам по закрытию кредита.
Я не знаю тонкостей и скрипт был написан при помощи чата гпт.
Возможно есть моменты которые нужно учесть, изменить, модифицировать, лимиты телеграм айпи итд
Я уже не знаю что делать и вообще копать ли в эту сторону..

У чат гпт спрашивали, почему его скрипт был заблокирован телеграмм? А вообще, это вам в поддержку телеги надо и там узнавать причины

у чат гпт конечно спрашивал, причин множество, но понимаю что в силу незнания ключевых моментов он мне и дает размытые ответы, мол не спамте, используйте в меру, следуйте правилам tos  итд..

Вам правильные советы дают, однако узнать о причинах блокировки в телеге надо в самой телеге

Да всё просто: вы долбите личными сообщениями, на вас каждый первый должник кидает репорт СПАМ - собрали с пяток жалоб -> добро пожаловать в бан. Думаю если вы ручками сами проделаете все те же самые действия, то так же отлетите в бан и автоматизация тут не причем.

хорошо, не пробовал, узнаю,спасибо

самое интересное что если придерживаться ограничения в 10 сообщений и отправлять сообщения руками, давать аккаунту "отдохнуть 1-2 часа", никаких ограничений не будет, проверено месяцами практики. но вот решился автоматизировать этот процесс, думаю тут проблема в том что телеграм айпи мои обращения считает неприемлимыми либо я нарушаю какие то лимиты, а какие, не известно , скрипт ограничивает аккаунт даже если меня сообщения непрочитаны, а просто доставлены

Telegram блокирует по той причине, что вы используете не ботов, а полноценные клиенты, это противоречит телеграм, я пытался уточнить это у поддержки, но мне так и не ответили.
В интернете этот вопрос был поднят очень давно
https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/issues/824
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76562915/telethon-accounts-get-banned-despite-proxy
https://qna.habr.com/q/828583
